# Is any API or SDK is available for snapchat integration in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, snapchat

How can I integrat snapchat in iOS. Is any API or SDK provided by snapchat like facebook or twitter?

Comment: found some php codes available but con't found any sdk or api for ios. Please help by link or suggestion.

Comment: I have same problem If you Found the answer please give me Replay ... Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It is against there terms to reverse engineer the app in order to send and receive snaps, however it is possible. I would like to say that to learn the API  it'll take you a long time and also a lot of will power.

However, to answer your question. Using this API you can send and receive Snaps in your app. But just be sure that you know. Logging in on your app will log out the user elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I saw your provided link previously. I need to send text message from my app to Snapchat. And also fetch the message history like Facebook or twitter.

Comment: Yep. I understand that. But Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for tutorials. Once again, reverse engineering this API is against their terms of use. I cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: @JulianE., have you tried to use the API described in the article you've mentioned?

Comment: That link is definitely NOT the official Snapchat API

Comment: Hello @JulianE. how can i login and logout with snapchat api.. if any api please replay me...